# how to Post list using ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

My problem here is how to send the list values to the controller upon an ajax post.  With my actual code, the list is null on post.

My view:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("UsersList", "Project", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Users" }))
{
     <div id="MyList" >
        <table>
        <thead>
        <tr><th></th><th>User</th><th>End date</th></tr>
        </thead>

    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.GetUsers)
       </table>
           </div> 

       <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#MyList).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 820,
                buttons: {
                    "Save": function () {
                        $("#Users").submit();
                    },

                    "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
    </script>
```

Model:

```
public class ProjectModel
    {

        public List<ProjectList>GetUsers{get;set;}

        }

  public class ProjectList
    {
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }

}
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UsersList(ProjectModel model)
        {
             return View(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending a list can be difficult. I think MVC 3.0 [has (in-built) support for sending JSON to the controller](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx) which would make this easier.

However with prior versions I think this article should be what your looking for:
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Effectively you give everything in the list the same name in your HTML (as the name will be what gets sent in the key/value string that gets sent and it will bind as a list.

For more complex items you name each object property but add an index to show which object they get attached too:

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/Create">

<input type="text" name="[0].Title" value="Curious George" />
<input type="text" name="[0].Author" value="H.A. Rey" />
<input type="text" name="[0].DatePublished" value="2/23/1973" />

<input type="text" name="[1].Title" value="Code Complete" />
<input type="text" name="[1].Author" value="Steve McConnell" />
<input type="text" name="[1].DatePublished" value="6/9/2004" />

<input type="text" name="[2].Title" value="The Two Towers" />
<input type="text" name="[2].Author" value="JRR Tolkien" />
<input type="text" name="[2].DatePublished" value="6/1/2005" />

<input type="submit" />
```